# Wanting to know if these formulas are correct for this very basic circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, analysis

Hello for the following diagram below, i was just wondering if these formulas are correct to finding what they state (i.e. Vout and V2). For V2 is R3 and C2 in parallel with C2?

[image]

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It is interesting to realize that this procedure (calculate V2 and replace it by a ficticious voltage source V2) makes use of the "Substitution Theorem" of network theory (which is not very well-known).

Comment: The correct answer is to find the thevin equivalent of looking into v2, then find vo, in your case because r3 is large you can approximate it this way. Or apply kcl..

Comment: for the frequency f to calculate the impedances it is the input signals frequency and not the cutoff frequencies correct?

Comment: Yes, f is the frequency of your input source

Comment: This circuit and its associated questions has been posted 2 times already: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305253/how-to-find-vout-for-the-following-band-pass-filter/305282#305282 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305253/how-to-find-vout-for-the-following-band-pass-filter/305282#305282. Why posting the same circuit/question a third time?

Comment: Why comment on a question that has been successfully answered?

Comment: If you have additional material related to your original question, you should edit the question rather than starting a new one. This just clutters up the site and creates unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those equations are correct, though clearly there is still additional working to get to your final answer.

Comment: for the frequency f to calculate the impedances it is the input signals frequency and not the cutoff frequencies correct?

Comment: Yeah, the impedance of reactive components is a function of the driving frequency ie: the input frequency.

Comment: Also remember that w is in radians per second, not hertz.